# Angular 4 webApi does not refresh

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, observable

I am building my first website in angular. I am trying to call a webAPI and show the result in my component. This is my service code:

```
getVeselVisit(): Observable<VesselVisit>
{
    let result = this.http.get(this.baseUrl + '/values/GetVesselVisit/')
        .map(res => <VesselVisit>(res.json()));

    alert(result);
    return result;
}
```

And this is my component:

```
constructor(private backEndService: BackEndService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.backEndService.getVeselVisit().subscribe(data => {
        this.vesselVisit = data;
    });
}
```

And this is my HTML view:

```
<p>Vessel VisitId: {{vesselVisit.idVisit}} |</p>
<p>Vessel Name: {{vesselVisit.vesselName}}</p>
```

VesselVisit class:

```
export class VesselVisit {
    constructor() {
        this.craneList = new Array<Crane>();
        this.idVisit = '1';
        this.vesselName = '';
    }

    idVisit: string;
    vesselName: string;
    craneList: Crane[];
}
```

This is de json I get from the service:

```
{"VesselVisit":{"craneList":[{"unitExecutedList":[{"idUnit":"MSCK1234567"},{"idUnit":"TCKU5633679"},{"idUnit":"TCNU2968547"},{"idUnit":"MSCU2587496"}],"unitPlannedList":[{"idUnit":"KKFU9784321"},{"idUnit":"KKFU7895521"},{"idUnit":"TCLU9968570"},{"idUnit":"BOLU7889332"},{"idUnit":"LIDU2001487"}],"idCrane":"QC11"},{"unitExecutedList":[{"idUnit":"MSCK1234567"},{"idUnit":"TCKU5633679"},{"idUnit":"MSCU2587496"},{"idUnit":"MOLU9685711"}],"unitPlannedList":[{"idUnit":"KKFU9784321"}],"idCrane":"QC33"}],"idVisit":"VisTEST","vesselName":"FARGAN"}}
```

I am getting the information, but I think I am not able to assign the response to the HTML view because I see nothing. I have tried to debug it and the data is there:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThVAO.png)

Comment: vesselVisit contains a bunch of unorder objects and arrays within itsself. You are getting the data but the data is not formated to be displayed in the html template. To display it in html template, you need it as an ordered tangible data. I also don't see idVisit and vesselName within vesselVisit following it.

Comment: Let me add the VesselVisit class, maybe it helps. I think the problem is I am not able to convert data object into a VesselVissti object

Comment: Json just added

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. In my service, I think I am returning an Observable<VesselVisit> in the proper way, can the mistake be when I assign this result to the variable in the component?

Comment: I am sure, that it will be a silly thing, but I am not able to find it. This is the result I get with | json: `"{\"VesselVisit\":{\"craneList\":[{\"unitExecutedList\":[{\"idUnit\":\"MSCK1234567\"},{\"idUnit\":\"TCKU5633679\"},{\"idUnit\":\"TCNU2968547\"},{\"idUnit\":\"MSCU2587496\"}],\"unitPlannedList\":[{\"idUnit\":\"KKFU9784321\"....`

Comment: I've realized about a strange thing. If I go to Augury in order to debug the website, (see the attached picture), I see all the information inside the vesselVisit object. If I click on this value, and then I click out of it, (lost focus), automatically the values are shown properly. It seems like the change mechanism was not working...

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I found the solution. I was running my webAPI and also my angular client on the same computer. I had to install Chrome extension CORS, in order to make it works. And I think this was the problem.

I have tried to publish my webAPI on a jsonplaceholder liked to a repository, and now, it works properly!